# Making sense of Firestore Security Rules - only allowing update for certain fields

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to use the Firestore security rules to edit some data, as follows, with a **transaction** in Flutter:

```
  Future sendRequest(uidSend, uidRec, pid, title) async {
    final crSend = ChatRequest(uid: uidRec, pid: pid, title: title);
    var _lsSend = List();
    _lsSend.add(crSend.toJson());

    final crRec = ChatRequest(uid: uidSend, pid: pid, title: title);
    var _lsRec = List();
    _lsRec.add(crRec.toJson());

    final uMSendDocref = userMetadataCollection.document(uidSend);
    final uMRecDocref = userMetadataCollection.document(uidRec);

    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      await transaction.update(uMSendDocref, <String, dynamic>{
        "sentRequests": FieldValue.arrayUnion(
          _lsSend,
        ),
      });
      await transaction.update(uMRecDocref, <String, dynamic>{
        "receivedRequests": FieldValue.arrayUnion(
          _lsRec,
        ),
      });
    });
  }
```

Notice that user1 is trying to update both his/her own data, as well as user2's. However, I only want user1 to be able to update this single field of user2's. I make my Firestore rules as such:

```
    match /userMetadata/{uid} {
      allow read: if uid == request.auth.uid || uid == 'PREVIEW';
      allow write: if uid == request.auth.uid && uid != 'PREVIEW';
      match /receivedRequests {
        allow read: if uid == request.auth.uid;
        allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != 'PREVIEW';
      }
      match /sentRequests {
        allow read: if uid == request.auth.uid;
        allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != 'PREVIEW';
      }
    }
```

`receivedRequests` (and `sentRequests`) only require that a user has a non-null auth to edit, ie, any user should be able to edit. However, I get a permissions error when running my transaction. Why is that? Perhaps I am misunderstanding Firestore rules? Perhaps the transaction is trying to do a read? Any thoughts?

UPDATE:

I tried using a batch:

```
  Future sendRequest(uidSend, uidRec, pid, title) async {
    //update own uM with post
    //update other uM with user

    final crSend = ChatRequest(uid: uidRec, pid: pid, title: title);
    var _lsSend = List();
    _lsSend.add(crSend.toJson());

    final crRec = ChatRequest(uid: uidSend, pid: pid, title: title);
    var _lsRec = List();
    _lsRec.add(crRec.toJson());

    final uMSendDocref = userMetadataCollection.document(uidSend);
    final uMRecDocref = userMetadataCollection.document(uidRec);

    var batch = Firestore.instance.batch();

    batch.updateData(uMSendDocref, <String, dynamic>{
      "sentRequests": FieldValue.arrayUnion(
        _lsSend,
      ),
    });

    batch.updateData(uMRecDocref, <String, dynamic>{
      "receivedRequests": FieldValue.arrayUnion(
        _lsRec,
      ),
    });

    return await batch.commit();
  }
```

Still does not work. Something is either incredibly unintuitive with Firestore, or there is a serious bug.

Another thing to note: some of the userMetadata might not currently have the fields that are being updated.

Comment: A transaction *does* do a read first.  That's how it gets the initial contents of the document to modify in the transaction handler function.  Maybe you want a batch write instead, which does not do a read first.

Comment: Alternatively, can I just read a portion of the document?

Comment: A read operation (in client-side SDKs and security rules) always reads the full document.

Comment: Don't think this is the case. See update.

Comment: @OP Aren't `receivedRequests` and `sentRequests` collection ? - how does "single field" work in this case?

Comment: Also, you can try `request.resource.data` to check with `resource.data` if only that particular field has updated.

Comment: request.auth.uid is the uid of the client making the connection. Obviously it cannot have 2 different values, which is what you are trying to do

Comment: The focus point is request.resource & resource variable, & not the request.auth https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource

Comment: not really what im asking. I want to match the right fields

Comment: 'match' as in? An example document before and after could be helpful.

Comment: I want to use the match keyword to set restrictions on certain firestore fields and not others.

Answer (score 1):

> I only want user1 to be able to update this single field of user2's.

A general way of allowing updation of only certain fields can be with checking diff of `request.resource.data` with `resource.data`.

Example documents that need to be updated have 3 field: name, city, standingBalance. We want anyone to change standingBalance but only the corresponding user to change his name and city.

The below example is considering that user1 should have complete `write` access to `user1's sendRequest` & only `single field update` access to `user2's receivedRequests`, there won't be much change in other scenarios.

```
match /userMetadata/{uid} {
  allow read: if uid == request.auth.uid || uid == 'PREVIEW';
  allow write: if uid == request.auth.uid && uid != 'PREVIEW';
  match /receivedRequests/{req} {
    allow read: if uid == request.auth.uid;
    allow write: if uid == request.auth.uid;
    allow update: if uid == request.auth.uid 
                 || (request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['name','city','standingBalance']) 
                     && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name
                     && request.resource.data.city == resource.data.city
                     && request.resource.data.standingBalance != resource.data.standingBalance
                     && request.auth.uid != null
                    )
  }
  match /sentRequests/{req} {
    allow read: if uid == request.auth.uid;
    allow write: if request.auth != request.auth.uid || request.auth.uid != 'PREVIEW';
  }
```

Checking with `hasOnly` ensures that no other key is added to the document. Also, I am unaware of what 'PREVIEW' is so do verify the rules yourself.

Having a `fieldsChanged` variable in firestore rules would be a good feature request ;)

Comment: Can you test it out? Also, if you could, how would you state your ultimate goal in one line? (Eg. I want to allow user1 to be able to update all of his fields and only 1 field of user2's document)

Comment: I want to use the matching rules to match exactly what I want without unexpected behavior. Yes this works but does not utilize matching rules.

Comment: understood a few things, updated my answer, LMK if there's still issues, happy to help :)